# How to set eclipselink cache expiry for all entities?

Tags: java, caching, jpa, eclipselink

I'd like to force eclipselink to invalidate the whole cache every hour. There is "expiry" attribute for @Cache annotation but I do not want to specify it on every entity because I want it to be the same for all of them. Is there a way to do it globally, e.g. in persistence.xml?

Update:
also, is it already possible to set expiry setting per entity in persistence.xml?

Comment: How you solve this issue ?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember now but I think nothing more than things from the link in answer

Answer (score 0):

On first part of the question:
http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg08292.html